# Find View by the ID from database (Not findViewById)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a `ListView` which displays info from database.(id , name and description).I'm using `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` to load all the information. How can I change the background of a certain `ListView` by the ID from the database? Not to all the views but for some of them?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the view? Views are not a 1:1 relation views get recycled on scrolling

Comment: the listview item gets populated in your adapter, I dont understand what clicking on it has to do with populating it

Comment: What actually changes when you need to set the background? Is this change related to database? Can't you change something on the data source and then reload the view to get what you wanted?

Comment: I guess you're confusing `id` and `position`

Comment: You can put your logic of how the view should render depending on the data provided in `getView` method of your list adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Custom Adapter and you can then change the background of the item in either the `getView` or  `bindView`(if the adapter is a subclass of CursorAdapter) method e.g.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertview, parent);

    int evenrow = ActionColorCoding.setHeadingColor(ctxt,
            callerintent,
            ActionColorCoding.getColorsPerGroup() -1 ) &
            ActionColorCoding.transparency_evenrow;
    int oddrow = evenrow & ActionColorCoding.transparency_oddrow;
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(evenrow);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(oddrow);
    }
    return view;
}
```

i.e. this sets alternating colour. In this case the colours are retrieved from a App defined pool of colours. **evenrow** and **oddrow** could be set directly to appropriate colours.

Assuming that **position** can be used to reliably ascertain the **id** of the row (whether or not that is the case depends upon the adapter's data source), then it's simply a matter of then obtaining the **id** and changing the background.

For a subclass of a CursorAdapter, then the Cursor (appropriately positioned) is passed to the `bindView` method so you can directly access the appropriate rows, although you can also use the `getCursor` method in the `getView` method and again it will be appropriately positioned.

`ArrayAdapters` very much depend upon the source. Often, wrongly, an `ArrayList<String>` is used as the source with just the values to be displayed held in the `Strings` (you see issues with updating and deleting data frequently on SO). It is far better to utilise `ArrayList<object_that_has_members_for_all_required_data>` as the source. Then the `getItem` method can retrieve the `object_that_has_members_for_all_required_data`.

As an example of actually using an **ID** in the custom CursorAdapter's `getView` method, the following code was added to the code above :-

```
    Cursor c = this.getCursor();
    if (c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DBAislesTableConstants.AISLES_ID_COL)) == 10 ) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFAAFFFF);
    }
```

The List then looks like :-

[image]

i.e. The background for Crisps has been changed, you can see how the items have alternating background colours.

#### Additional

Here's a **very simple** example App that changes the colour of an item by clicking a button in that item.

#### The item layout (TextView and Button) **item_list_with_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hit Me"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### The DatabaseHelper **DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_MYTABLE = "_mytable";
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_NAME = "_name";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TB_MYTABLE +
                "(" +
                COL_MYTABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_MYTABLE_NAME + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addRow(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_NAME,name);
        return mDB.insert(TB_MYTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        return mDB.query(TB_MYTABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

#### The Custom Cursor Adapter **CsrAdapter.java**

```
public class CsrAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CsrAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_with_button,viewGroup,false);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((LinearLayout)view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(0xFFAAFFAA);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView text1 = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_NAME)));
    }
}
```

- NOTE the button.setOnClickListener ... onCLick
- NOTE I beleieve that you should really check that the parent is as expected before casting

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    CsrAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = this.findViewById(R.id.lisview);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Test1");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Test2");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Test3");

        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getAllRows();
        mAdapter = new CsrAdapter(this,mCsr,0);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

- Note will add 3 rows every run.

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lisview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### When First run :-

[image]

After Hitting a few buttons :-

[image]

Comment: +1 That's great!! I assume this load the color as soon as it loads the list...but do you have any idea how i can make it to change the color on button click

Comment: That's great I'm just working on it as well. Thank you for the help its really appreciated!!